# DisplayPort cable 2.5V for non standard use

Tags: voltage, pcb, lvds

I want to use a DisplayPort connector and cable for transmission of a custom 8b/10b protocol (not the DisplayPort protocol). Does anyone know if these cables are good for use at 2.5V instead of 3.3V or if any degradation of the signal would result?

Comment: It is a really bad idea to reuse connector types for incompatible signals. People are going to connect your device to a 3.3V DP output, resulting in any or all of smoke, fire, shame and recrimination.

Comment: @SimonRichter only if OP is doing this as a mass produced product instead of a one off project

Comment: It's definitely a one-off and the others connecting to it are using the same voltage levels.